# Centralized orchestration of Secret Shares for SMPC

Tags: secret-sharing, multiparty-computation

With regards to SMPC with additive secret sharing, the protocol I am using involves a centralized node(the querier) orchestrating the share creation at client end via setting their random seeds. Now this allows the central party to reconstruct data. My question is does there exist an implementation with no member-member connections such that additive shares can be created without the central party knowing what they are? Feel free to ask for any more details that I may have missed.

Comment: Do you allow Alice encrypting a message with Bob's public key, and sending that ciphertext to the central party, who forwards it to Bob?  With that, it's pretty straight-forward - however, I don't know if that is what you're looking for...

Comment: That might work actually, but I figured out a slightly different approach where as new parties join in they are assigned one seed from predecessor and 1 created by them. When no new parties join the first and last are linked wrapping up the process. Yours will be more appropriate from a pure security point of view, so thank for this idea

Comment: Can you not view the central server as the network who's only suppose to relay messages? Then you can use any MPC protocol that uses private and authenticated channels.